# How do I use substring-before and substring-after to separate a number (within parenthesis) and alpha text string into XML elements in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I use substring-before and substring-after to separate a number (within parenthesis) and alpha text string into XML elements in XSLT 1.0?

My input XML is:

```
<root>
<subsection>(1)This is level 2 para.</subsection>
<subsection>(2)This is a another level 2 para.</subsection>
</root>
```

I would like my output to be:

```
<lev2>
<number>1</number>
<text>This is level 2 para.</text>
</lev2>
<lev2>
<number>2</number>
<text>This is a another level 2 para.</text>
</lev2>
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not look too difficult… What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm new to XSLT and not sure where to start, any example or step through would be great.

Comment: Please show the XSL that you have written so far.  If you have not written at least a skeleton XSL then you have bigger problems than figuring out how to parse a text string.

Comment: Also, this is primarily an approach/thought problem, secondarily an XPath problem and somewhere *after that* it's an XSLT problem. If you have two functions called `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`, no matter the language, how would you have to call them to get the `"1"` out of `"(1)This is level 2 para."`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following template will result in requested output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="subsection"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="subsection">
 <xsl:variable name="subsection" select="."/>
 <xsl:variable name="sectionNumber" 
       select="substring-after(substring-before($subsection, ')'), '(')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="sectionText" select="substring-after( $subsection , ')')"/>
  <lev2>
   <number>
    <xsl:value-of select="$sectionNumber"/>
   </number>
   <text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$sectionText"/>
   </text>
  </lev2>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As it's a basic question, just for starters as example for your further proceedings in getting along with XSLT. The functions substring-before and substring-after are very self-explaining. For reference you should just check http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt and e.g. http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_substring-before.html

Comment: Hi matthias_h, that works great thank you, I shall try amending this code for other similar conversions. I shall read through the URLs, they are a good reference source, thanks again.